# How to create df dynamically while looping list in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

```
def create_df(src,header=None):
    df =spark.read.csv(src, header=header)
    return df

result = source_df.filter(f.col('Job_name') == job_name).select(source_df['dfname'],source_df['srcpath']).collect()

for x in result:
    src=str('"' +x[1] + '"'.strip(' '))
    src = str(src)
    x[0] = create_df(src, header=True)   //throwing an uft-8 encod
```

result is a list having 2 columns called dfname and source path, need to loop the result list and based on the dfname value need to create pass df name dynamically.

```
| dfname     | SPath        |
|------------+--------------|
| Account_Df | s3://path... |
| ProdMet_Df | s3://path... |
```

Based on the df name need to create dfnames?

expected output 
Account_Df and ProdMet_Df two sepate dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure you need to do this, you can update the `globals()` dictionary to create a variable in the global (module) namespace. Your last line of code should then be:

```
    globals()[x[0]] = create_df(src, header=True)
```